# C# Collection for controls readonly

Tags: c#, controls, readonly, controlcollection

found the following code: [Alle Controls einer Form auf Readonly setzen](https://blog.schelian.de/2008/03/alle-controls-einer-form-auf-readonly-setzen-winforms-c/)

But how have my Control.ControlCollection look like that I can use this method?
I tried the following but it is not working:

```
Control[] ControlCollection = new Control[] { textbox1 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the parameter type to `IEnumerable<Control> controls`

You can also provide an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) to convert `ControlCollection` to `IEnumerable<Control>`:

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> AsEnumerable(this ControlCollection controls)
    => controls?.Cast<Control>() ?? Enumerable.Empty<Control>();
```

So if you want to use your `SetReadOnly` method with `ControlCollection`:

```
SetReadOnly(this.Controls.AsEnumerable()); // all controls of the form are set readonly
```